# Run a JUnit Test with multiple Spring contexts in different projects

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test

I have a generic code base that I need to test with different implementations and runtime configurations. Think services with multiple DAO implementations. I have generic unit tests which test the Dao interface (need the Dao autowired), and I want to invoke these from different projects.

Essentially I want something like this. 
In the shared, generic project my tests will live. 
So essentially, in shared project I have my tests, for example.

```
public class ApiTest {

@Autowired
DaoBase myDao;

    @Test
    public void testSomething(){
    }
}
```

Then in the other project(s) that implement the Dao, I would have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ImplementationConfigA.class })
public class ImplemtationTesterA {

  //somehow invoke ApiTest.class?
}
```

.

```
@Configuration
public class ImplementationConfigA{
    @Bean 
    DaoBase daoBase {
        return new DaoImplementationGraphDB(); 
    }
}
```

Again, there are multiple projects that implement the DAO layer in different ways, and I want to share the generic tests.

If I could combine @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and @RunWith(Suite.class), it would be exactly what I desire, but that doesn't seem possible. i.e. this would be effectively what I want, which is not possible:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ImplementationConfigA.class })
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({   ApiTest.class })
public class ImplemtationTesterA {
...
```

There's got to be a trick to get something like this working.. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

```
@Configuration
@Profile("profileA")
public class ImplementationConfigA{
    @Bean 
    DaoBase daoBase {
        return new DaoImplementationGraphDB(); 
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ImplementationConfigA.class })
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({   ApiTest.class })
@ActiveProfiles("profileA");
public class ImplemtationTesterA {
...
```

Comment: I don't think using profiles solves this problem; which is, From ImplementationTesterA I need to have it run all the tests in the class ApiTest with the context specified in ImplementationConfigA. In other words, Spring's SpringJUnit4ClassRunner doesn't provide an equivalent mechanism as @RunWith(Suite.class) and @Suite.SuiteClasses({   ApiTest.class }), at least as far as I can find.

Comment: But you can achieve the same thing with profiles, which is like a tag of which set of tests to run.

Comment: But I can't combine @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and @RunWith(Suite.class). So from the Spring test class ImplemtationTesterA, how do I get it to run all the tests in class ApiTest (which is in a different project)?  ApiTest has the generic tests for the API and is not aware of the various implementations or configurations for those implementations. All it knows is it expects an implementation of the interface to be injected. I want the multiple implementations to each be able to use these shared tests.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update: 
I ended placing all the shared tests is one project, and then in each DAO implementation project creating a "dummy" test class that extended each shared test class. Not as convenient as defining a suite since each test class had to be duplicated in each implementation project, but it works.

So in the original example, the only change necessary was to make ImplemtationTesterA extend ApiTest.